# "If all goes well,..." VS "If everything goes well,..."

Tags: word-choice

I have the following sentence:

> If all goes well, I'll graduate in June.

Is it correct? I have never heard the words *"all goes well"* before. Maybe *"everything goes well"* would be better choice?

Answer (score 3):

**"If all goes well" is way more common** than "if everything goes well", due to its idiomatic use. Usually, it would be better to say "everything", but it's part of a set phrase. If you'd like to use "everything, it might be better as "If everything goes according to plan". Or "If everything goes perfectly".

Comment: Is it ("if everything goes well") a good phrase in formal writing?